# Jquery Datepicker error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, datepicker, powerbuilder

I'm using a datepicker in my mvc3 application. the problem is that the controls below it are visable when it expands. this only happens in IE 8 which is being loading in a powerbuilder application. It works fine in IE9, FF8, and opera11.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552326/ie-6-select-controlscombo-box-over-menu  this explains on IE6, i don't know when was it corrected

Comment: Don't think this is my problem, my version of IE is 8. Plus it only happens when running inside the powerbuilder application. It works fine when running on my local ie.

Comment: What is the z-index of datepicker and select box?

Comment: I think we need some code examples or more information if we are going to be able to provide you with useful information.

Comment: Normally I fix this kind of design problems with "overflow:hidden" to the two objects, specially the object overlapping the other. But we need to see the html and css, make a screenshoot of firebug or others and upload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224504/error-using-webbrowser-control-inside-powerbuilder-app-when-select-an-item-in-s/11228575#11228575) talks about the registry key FEATURE_USE_WINDOWEDSELECTCONTROL affecting how a web browser control behaves in a PowerBuilder window. I haven't tested anything, but is *sounds* relevant based on the name of the key, even though your issue is visual and the referenced question talks about a crash.